# Rendering a template based on object type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, rendering

I'm writing a small forum app where users can create different types of forums. For example, an announcements, a discussions, or a questions forum.

The Forum model has many posts, and a `forum_type` column. I would like to render `posts#show` using different template, based on the `@post.forum_type` column.

So each forum, based on its type, will have a distinct appearance for its posts.

How I can I do this without littering my code with `if @post.forum_type == 'something'` ... ?

Comment: Among other ideas, what if you were to just use something like: `render :template => 'forums/forum_type_here'` but use that `@post.forum_type` variable inside the `render` statement... something like this: `render :template => @post.forum_type`?  *(Or maybe appending something onto that `@post.forum_type` variable if it is a string.)*

Comment: Good idea. Not as clean as I want, but a great alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegation.  Write a post renderer, and then implement one concrete renderer subclass per forum type:

```
class Post
  attr_accessor :forum_type       
end

class BaseRenderer
  def renderer_for(post) 
    # create the correct renderer for the post here
  end

  def render_post(post)
    renderer = renderer_for(post)
    renderer.to_html  # return the results
end

class ForumAPostRenderer
  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end

  def render
    # render the post for forum A here\
  end
end

class ForumBPostRenderer
  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end

  def render
    #render post for forum B here
  end
end
```

This means that you can easily skin different forums by implementing only a renderer and adding a little bit of logic to the renderer_for method.

Comment: Thank you! At risk of sound slow, (I'm very new to this), where would these classes live, what directory? And what would the calling code look like? Would it be in the controller or the view?

Comment: They're view logic, not controller logic.  I would call them from the Controller - they're essentially just slightly more complex templates that contain some conditional presentation logic in a more manageable method.

Comment: Sorry to sound obtuse, but the `render` method would render the html appropriate to the object? Or would I call a template from it?

Comment: Whichever you prefer.  Obviously, using a template would be better from a maintenance point of view, but the point is that by doing the above you've separated out how to decide which template to render from the act of rendering that template.